# Creating an image that contains probability of each pixel

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

How do I produce image that every pixel contains their probability of being "an object"?

Comment: what have you tried in terms of code?

Comment: This depends on your problem. What do the images look like? What objects are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of different models for different tasks. You can try using UNet if you need to segment a single object (e.g. balloon/no balloon).

If you need to detect multiple objects you can try using Mask R-CNN.

There is a tutorial for [UNet](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation)

P. S. for object detection tasks I recommend using PyTorch rather than TensorFlow.
It is a lot of ready-to-use PyTorch code for instance segmentation task.
Here is a [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html) for PyTorch Mask R-CNN

Comment: Thank you! This seems helpful.